# How to show progress bar (tqdm) while using multiprocessing in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, progress-bar, tqdm

I have the following code with `create_data()` referring to the function I already defined before.

```
%%time
from tqdm import tqdm
from multiprocessing import Pool
import pandas as pd
import os

with Pool(processes=os.cpu_count()) as pool:
    results = pool.map(create_data, date)
    data = [ent for sublist in results for ent in sublist]
    data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = cols)
    data.to_csv("%s"%str(date), index=False)
```

I basically want to call `create_data()` while also passing the date argument. Then all the results obtained will be gathered into the `results` variable. I will then combine them all into a list and convert it to a data frame. The function `create_data` is quite heavy in computation and thus takes a long time to compute. That's why I need the progress bar to see the processes.

I have tried changing the line into the following.

```
results = list(tqdm(pool.map(create_od, date), total = os.cpu_count()))
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. I have waited for quite some time and there is no progress bar showing up. How am I supposed to do here?

Answer (score 10):

cf [multiprocessing.Pool.map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) :

> It blocks until the result is ready

and [tqdm.tqdm](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm/#tqdm-objects) :

> Decorate an iterable object, returning an iterator which acts exactly like the original iterable, but prints a dynamically updating progressbar every time a value is requested.

So the `map`ping is completely finished before `tqdm` ever gets called.

I reproduced with this code :

```py
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm
from multiprocessing import Pool


def crunch(numbers):
    print(numbers)
    sleep(2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        print("mapping ...")
        results = tqdm(pool.map(crunch, range(40)), total=40)
        print("done")
```

which prints :

```
mapping ...
0
3
6
[...]
37
38
  0%|          | 0/40 [00:00<?, ?it/s]done
```

Instead you should use the **lazy** version [`multiprocessing.Pool.imap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap) : it will return immediately a generator that you have to iterate over to get the actual results, which can be wrapped in `tqdm`.

```py
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Pool

from tqdm import tqdm


def crunch(numbers):
    # print(numbers)  # commented out to not mess the tqdm output
    sleep(2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        print("mapping ...")
        results = tqdm(pool.imap(crunch, range(40)), total=40)
        print("running ...")
        tuple(results)  # fetch the lazy results
        print("done")
```

which prints :

```py
mapping ...
running ...
  0%|          | 0/40 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
  2%|▎         | 1/40 [00:02<01:35,  2.45s/it]
 12%|█▎        | 5/40 [00:04<00:27,  1.26it/s]
 22%|██▎       | 9/40 [00:06<00:19,  1.58it/s]
 32%|███▎      | 13/40 [00:08<00:15,  1.74it/s]
 42%|████▎     | 17/40 [00:10<00:12,  1.83it/s]
 52%|█████▎    | 21/40 [00:12<00:10,  1.89it/s]
 62%|██████▎   | 25/40 [00:14<00:07,  1.92it/s]
 72%|███████▎  | 29/40 [00:16<00:05,  1.95it/s]
 82%|████████▎ | 33/40 [00:18<00:03,  1.96it/s]
100%|██████████| 40/40 [00:20<00:00,  1.95it/s]
done
```

(the progress bar is on multiple lines because my PyCharm on Windows terminal does not support `\r`, but it should work fine on yours)

Comment: interesting, I will need to try this later. I have a question, I have no idea what number to put in the total parameter. In your example, the total is the same as the number of iteration. What should I put in my case?

Comment: This answer would be far more useful if your example did not involve `crunch_numbers` but instead showed how `imap` could be used with the OP's actual problem. Your `results` variable does *not*  have the same semantics as the OP's `results` variable and after you execute `tuple(results)`, any useful results are gone forever.

Comment: @catris25 if you don't know the total, just don't give it to `tqdm`, which will just not display an average time to complete. It is not required, ignore it from my answer.

Comment: @Booboo I would have liked to use the OP's code, but it was not provided, so I created a dummy `cruch_numbers` function as a placeholder. Indeed, my `results` variable is misnamed, it would be something more like a "futures", and the results would be the result of calling `tuple` on the futures, or it could be used in a `for` loop instead.

Comment: For anyone who find this, `progress_bar` is not needed and is actually the reason for multiple lines output. Just deleting it and keeping `results = tqdm(pool...` will make pycharm or probably any other environment output just one refreshing bar.

Comment: @IgorAgafonov you are right, I made a mistake creating 2 different progress bars. I update the answer, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

See the answer of @Lenormnu, who is on the right track.

However the problem with the `imap` method is that it is guaranteed to return its results in the order of the arguments. So if the processing of the very first element of the `date` list takes extremely long (it is the last task to finish), the progress bar will not advance until that task completes. But by then all of the other submitted tasks have completed and the progress bar will immediately jump to 100%. Admittedly, this is not likely to happen. But it would be better if you could process results in completion order. `imap_unordered` could be used but to recover the results in the order of task submission would required you to first modify your `create_data` function.

If you use class `ProcessPoolExecutor` from the `concurrent.futures` module for multiprocessing, you actually do not have to modify your `create_data` function at all since method `submit` creates `Future` instances that you can store in a dictionary as keys whose values are indexes and then apply the `as_completed` method to the dictionary to return the completed tasks in their order of completion and recover the index. Here I am being a bit more clever so no sorting is required:

```py
import tqdm
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
import pandas as pd
import os

with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as executor:
    # total argument for tqdm is just the number of submitted tasks:
    with tqdm.tqdm(total=len(date)) as progress_bar:
        futures = {}
        for idx, dt in enumerate(date):
            future = executor.submit(create_data, dt)
            futures[future] = idx
        results = [None] * len(date) # pre_allocate slots
        for future in as_completed(futures):
            idx = futures[future] # order of submission
            results[idx] = future.result()
            progress_bar.update(1) # advance by 1
    data = [ent for sublist in results for ent in sublist]
    data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = cols)
```

Comment: Updating the progress bar more in-sync with job completions is nice to have, but makes for a solution less simple than mine, and was not what the OP asked for. However, for other readers, who could have this specific need, your solution looks good, thanks !